# Button to second activity crashes app on start

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I've been trying to crack this all day reading many many posts and tutorials etc and I'm 0% closer to solving it. I think theres a high chance of a more experienced coder cracking it easily so posting it in the hope someone will correct it and other noobs will see it.

I have a simple button *bagButton* that when pressed should transition from *MainActivity* to *BagActivity*

On launch of the app it stops and I never get a chance to see it run let alone press the button.

When I take out this code the app runs fine (but obviously does not transition):

```
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonBag);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BagActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

The greater *MainActivity.java* code is:

```
package nz.co.gamekeeper;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonBag);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BagActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

    }

}
```

The logcat output is as follows:

```
05-11 16:45:02.494: I/Process(1437): Sending signal. PID: 1437 SIG: 9
05-11 16:46:12.599: D/AndroidRuntime(2028): Shutting down VM
05-11 16:46:12.599: W/dalvikvm(2028): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4182b2a0)
05-11 16:46:12.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2028): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 16:46:12.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2028): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nz.co.gamekeeper/nz.co.gamekeeper.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-11 16:46:12.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
05-11 16:46:12.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
05-11 16:46:12.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
05-11 16:46:12.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
05-11 16:46:12.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-11 16:46:12.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-11 16:46:12.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
05-11 16:46:12.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 16:46:12.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-11 16:46:12.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
05-11 16:46:12.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
05-11 16:46:12.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-11 16:46:12.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2028): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-11 16:46:12.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at nz.co.gamekeeper.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
05-11 16:46:12.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
05-11 16:46:12.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
05-11 16:46:12.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
05-11 16:46:12.599: E/AndroidRuntime(2028):     ... 11 more
```

The XML has two parts *activity_main.xml*:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="nz.co.gamekeeper.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

And its *fragment_main.xml*:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="nz.co.gamekeeper.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/buttonBag"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="@string/button_text_bag" />

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/buttonSeason"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="@string/button_text_season" />

         </TableRow>

         <TableRow
             android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1" >

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/buttonMates"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="@string/button_text_mates" />

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/buttonBirds"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="@string/button_text_birds" />

         </TableRow>

         <TableRow
             android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1" >

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/buttonSetup"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="@string/button_text_setup" />

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/buttonSync"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:text="@string/button_text_sync" />

         </TableRow>

         <TableRow
             android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonSpare1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/button_text_spare1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonSpare2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/button_text_spare2" />

         </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried cleaning it, restarting Eclipse, getting a better idea of the error by adding logs, trying different Intent args, making sure manifest is ok, plus loads more...

Can anyone shed light on what I might try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with the `Button` view.  You have the `Button` view only in the `Fragment layout` not in the `MainActivity` Layout, but you are trying to access the button from `MainActivity`.

So, you can access the Button only in `Fragment`.

Move the code from `MainActivity` to `PlaceholderFragment` like below

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    // you can find the button here from the fragment layout
    Button b = (Button) rootView .findViewById(R.id.buttonBag);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), BagActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Adding it to the fragment was something I attempted but I missed *rootView .findViewById(..*.

The *MainActivity.this* was giving an error (out of scope) but was solved by adding *v.getContext()*

Comment: Good.You can use also use getActivity().

Answer (score 0):

`activity_main.xml` does not contain a view with the id `@id/buttonBag`, that view is in `fragment_main.xml`. When you try to find the view in the `MainActivity`, you get a NPE because that view doesn't exist in the layout you just inflated! You should add the `OnClickListener` in `onCreateView(...)` of `PlaceholderFragment`, like so:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonBag);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), BagActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Cheers, I appreciate your comments, they helped a lot.